# SSO with Spring Security 3.x.x

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-sign-on

I need to implement SSO with Spring Security 3.2.9 / Java 1.7 / Spring MVC, and upgrading to Spring Security 4 and Java 1.8 isn't an option. I was able to integrate CAS 4, except it fails after login redirect because  of the version of Spring Security we are using (we don't want to use any versions of CAS earlier than 4).  I have also looked at Gluu and Keycloak, but it looks like both require Java 1.8 on the client side and Spring Security 4.

The only SSO platform that I have been able to find that meets my requirements is MITREid Connect, but the downside of that is it doesn't look like there is any React library if we want to use that in the future.

Does anyone have experience integrating SSO on older versions of Spring Security? This is my first time implementing SSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security 3.x with Spring Security SAML extension works well to achieve standards based SSO.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at tha